# Adding Breadcrumb Navigation

Tags: 2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 and at this point I have not been using bread crumb navigation. When I migrated a site from my old SharePoint 2003 environment it brought over breadcrumb navigation to a page and it is very useful so I would like to add it to the rest of the SharePoint 2013 pages. I went into the default.aspx file that was created during the site migration and found the code below is what is adding the bread crumb navigation.

My question is how do I get this added to all of the other existing pages and included on new pages as they are created?

```
<tr class="s4-die">
       <td class="ms-pagebreadcrumb">
          <asp:SiteMapPath SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" id="ContentMap" SkipLinkText="" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional" runat="server"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more complex issue than can be explained in a single answer.  But this topic has been blogged about many times.  Just Google it.

For example:

[SharePoint 2013 breadcrumb](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/)

Answer (score 0):

To apply a breadcrumb to all of the other existing pages and included on new pages as they are created you should add it to master page by following the mentioned steps below :

- Open Sharepoint Designer 2013 and navigate to your Master Page.
- Place your cursor right inside the opening tag.
- At the above Sharepoint Designer 2013 ribbon, select INSERT > ASP.NET > scroll down to the Navigation section and select SiteMapPath.
- Save the file and there you have it.

Hope it helps you

Comment: The master page is an html file not an aspx file. When I try to do what you mention above it gives me an error. If I force it to save the site no longer loads.

Comment: Are you tried to check this http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/